# Graphic representation of a triangle using ArrayPlot

Tags: plotting, matrix, approximation

So I need to write a function which takes natural integer $n$ and returns graphical representation of a matrix $n \times n$ using `ArrayPlot[]`.
This matrix has to be pixel approximation of equilateral triangle which get better and better as $n$ increases.

I figured out a set of equilateral triangle points which is $$P=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2:y<\sqrt{3}x+\frac{a\sqrt{3}}{2},y<-\sqrt{3}x+\frac{a\sqrt{3}}{2},y>0\}$$
where $a$ is side length of this triangle.

```
f1[x_, a_] := -Sqrt[3]*x + (a*Sqrt[3])/2
f2[x_, a_] := Sqrt[3]*x + (a*Sqrt[3])/2
matrix[n_] := ConstantArray[0, {n, n}]
(...)
drawapprox[n_] := ArrayPlot[matrix[n], Mesh -> True]
```

So I make zero $n \times n$ matrix and I want to put $1$ if a point belongs to $P$ but I don't know how to put together points from the plane to this  0-1 matrix to make it works. After that I just want to use `ArrayPlot[]` function to draw new 0-1 matrix which represents triangle.

How do I make up the missing (...) part?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** An alternative method using [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html):

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, sa, aplot2]
f1[x_, a_] := -Sqrt[3]*x + (a*Sqrt[3])/2
f2[x_, a_] := Sqrt[3]*x + (a*Sqrt[3])/2

sa[a_] := SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; 
     a - i < f1[j - (a + Boole[OddQ[a]])/2, a] && 
     a - i < f2[j - (a + Boole[OddQ[a]])/2, a] -> 1, {a, a}]
aplot2[a_] := ArrayPlot[sa[a], Mesh -> All]

Row[aplot2 /@ Range[3, 21, 2]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, aplot]
f1[x_, a_] := -Sqrt[3]*x + (a*Sqrt[3])/2
f2[x_, a_] := Sqrt[3]*x + (a*Sqrt[3])/2
aplot[a_] := ArrayPlot[Boole @ MapIndexed[
       a - #2[[1]] < f1[#2[[2]] - (a + Boole[OddQ[a]])/2, a] && 
       a - #2[[1]] < f2[#2[[2]] - (a + Boole[OddQ[a]])/2, a] &, 
     ConstantArray[0, {a, a}], {2}], Mesh -> All];

Row[Show[aplot@#, Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], SSSTriangle[#, #, #]}]] & /@
 Range[3, 21, 2]]
```

[image]

With `a = 101;` and `Mesh -> None`, we get

```
a = 1001; 
ap1001 = ArrayPlot[Boole@MapIndexed[
      a - #2[[1]] < f1[#2[[2]] - (a + Boole[OddQ[a]])/2, a] && 
      a - #2[[1]] < f2[#2[[2]] - (a + Boole[OddQ[a]])/2, a] &, 
    ConstantArray[0, {a, a}], {2}], Mesh -> None];

Graphics[{ap1001[[1]], FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], 
  SSSTriangle[1001, 1001, 1001]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!